# Get length of Admob Interstitial video ad before it is displayed in Android

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I am trying to use the interstitial video ads in tight time frames so I need to know the length of the video before it is displayed. Is it possible to get the length of the video before it is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know neither class of InterstitialAds

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd

nor its listener

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener

provide this data.